# Чтение данных из файла и сохранение в массив

Tags: objective-c, ios

Есть файл допустим с именем level1.lvl
в нем строки:

```
10;24;cube1  
14;55;cube2  
итд...
```

Требуется прочитать этот файл и заполнить 3 массива:
Вот что допусти должны содержать массивы db1-3 после прочтения 1 строки:

> db1[0] = 10;   
>  db2[0] = 23;  
> db3[0] = cube1;

Занимаюсь Objective-C пару дней, не могу догнать как такое реализовать.

**Дополнено.**

Верно?

```
NSString* fileName = @"filename.txt";
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: fileName];
NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];    
    NSUInteger count = [lines count];
    NSUInteger i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSArray *readed = nil;
        NSString *element = [lines objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *readed = [element componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
        [block_x objectAtIndex:i] = [readed objectAtIndex:0];
        [block_y objectAtIndex:i] = [readed objectAtIndex:1];
        [block_type objectAtIndex:i] = [readed objectAtIndex:2];
    }
```

Comment: Извините за дурацкий вопрос (совет), а fgets() и sscanf() в Objective-C будут работать ?

Comment: будут

Comment: Тогда читайте файл по строкам fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),File) и выбирайте данные rc = sscanf (buf,"%d;%d;%s",&db1[i],&db2[i],str). db3[i] = strdup(str); 

Если rc == 3 ОК, иначе - ошибка в формате. 

Пара fgets()/sscanf() используется для надежности и упрощения анализа ошибок в формате ввода, чтобы избежать зацикливания на fscanf() при ее тривиальном применении.

Answer (score 2):

У меня сейчас нет возможности набросать и проверить код, поэтому просто изложу как бы я попытался решить эту задачу:

1. Считал бы файл с помощью [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:];
2. получил бы массив строк вида 10;24;cube1 с помощью componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator используя как разделитель переход строки
3. циклом по массиву разбил бы каждую строку на подстроки той же функцией, разделитель ";" и распихал бы эти подстроки по массивам (NSMutableArray)

Answer (score 2):

Нет.
Во-первых, вы так не прочитаете файл т.к. до него нужно указывать путь:

```
 //если лежит в документах проекта
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);      
NSString *storePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.txt"];

 //если лежит в бандле
NSString *storePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:NULL];
```

Во-вторых, не сработает прямое присвоение [block_x objectAtIndex:i] = [readed objectAtIndex:0]; , это же не сишный массив, скорее что-то типа vector из c++, должно быть [block_x addObject:[readed objectAtIndex:0]]; (добавит в конец массива, есть вариант функции и с указанием в какое место добавить, но она не переписывает значение под индексом, а сдвигает его на одну позицию). Кроме того, для чтения файла нужно указать кодировку и можно заменить кусок

```
NSUInteger i;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    NSArray *readed = nil;
    NSString *element = [lines objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *readed = [element componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
```

на

```
for(NSString *element in lines)
{
    NSArray *readed = [element componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
```